# nodejs writing to array not in required format

Tags: node.js

In my script, I am reading a file and when I do the output is like :

```
console.log(fileData)

    {"Name": "Raj","Subject":"Maths","Marks": 3},{"Name": "Elan","Subject":"English","Marks": 1},{"Name": "Preet","Subject":"Science","Marks": 4},{"Name": "Dan","Subject":"History","Marks": 2}
```

When I do array push like :

```
var marks =[];
marks.push(fileData)
console.log(marks)
```

I am getting the console as

```
[ '{"Name": "Raj","Subject":"Maths","Marks": 3},{"Name": "Elan","Subject":"English","Marks": 1},{"Name": "Preet","Subject":"Science","Marks": 4},{"Name": "Dan","Subject":"History","Marks": 2}' ]
```

But the output i am expecting is to be like :

```
[{"Name": "Raj","Subject":"Maths","Marks": 3},{"Name": "Elan","Subject":"English","Marks": 1},{"Name": "Preet","Subject":"Science","Marks": 4},{"Name": "Dan","Subject":"History","Marks": 2}]
```

What should I do to get the output in the above mentioned format. Please help

Comment: console.log remove quotations when printing, your fileData  is string, you need to call: `marks.push(JSON.parse(fileData))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its multiple objects it must be an array if it's not then you need to make it an array.

I've added here for an example.

```
const fs =require("fs");
var fileData = `[${fs.readFileSync('./a.txt', 'utf8')}]` 
fileData = JSON.parse(fileData)
console.log(fileData)
```